# Unable to upgrade from Kafka 0.8.2.2 to 0.10.0.0

Tags: apache-kafka

Trying upgrade from Kafka 0.8.x to Kafka 0.10.x

I did everything what the Kafka documents tell
(http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade_10)

But I still don't see the Kafka being upgraded. I did:

1. Insert "inter.broker.protocol.version" and "log.message.format.version" into server.properties
2. Stop broker -> update "inter.broker.protocol.version" to have current Kafka version -> start broker. Repeated this on all the brokers in the cluster.
3. Update protocol version to be "0.10.0.0" and did a restart on all the brokers.

I dont think Kafka upgrade ever happened. 
I still find the old jars and I dont find the new bash scripts that are to be available when you upgrade to 0.10.0.0

Not sure if I did it right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you skipped Step 2:

> Upgrade the brokers. This can be done a broker at a time by simply bringing it down, updating the code, and restarting it.

After adding `inter.broker.protocol.version` and `log.message.format.version` to the config, for each broker, you need to stop it, put the new JARs (for 1.0) and restart it.

You can get the latest 1.0 JAR from http://kafka.apache.org/downloads#1.0.2

Comment: I did it. It still doesn't work. I dont see it upgraded. And I find nothing useful in logs.